# Microsoft Word Mail Merge Not Keeping Text Formatting When Sending Emails

Tags: microsoft-word, email, microsoft-outlook

For example, in Word I will have a message formatted like this:

```
Dear x

Paragraph 1.

Paragraph 2.

Paragraph 3.

Regards, 

y
```

But after sending the email through Outlook, the text appears like this:

```
Dear x Paragraph 1. Paragraph 2. Paragraph 3. Regards, y
```

What needs to be done to maintain basic text spacing/formatting when using mail merge?

Comment: Are you using HTML formatting in Outlook for your message?  That is pretty much the same as Word. Don’t use Text as that destroys formatting

Answer (score 0):

Did you check it in Preview Results? Is it correct?

In the **Mail format** box, please make sure you have chosen **HTML** (the default setting)  to send the document as the body of the email message.

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/use-mail-merge-to-send-bulk-email-messages-0f123521-20ce-4aa8-8b62-ac211dedefa4

Comment: @aaronth07 How about this issue now?